# какие строки удалить в файле .db, чтобы сбросить пароль?

Tags: android, база-данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно попасть в приложение на моем старом андроиде, которое защищено паролем. Я извлек файл с данными. Можно ли удалить какие-либо пункты, чтобы сбросить пароль? Удалить все пункты я уже пробовал - пароль сбрасывался, но данные были зашифрованы.

Comment: Если данные зашифрованы с помощью пароля, то расшифровать без правильного пароля не выйдет.

Comment: @woesss благодарю за ответ, я примерно так и предполагал.

Comment: Вообще нужно разбираться как программа их шифрует. Возможно для этого достаточно данных, записанных в базе, а пароль не даёт войти в саму программу. Вам нужно декомпилировать код и изучать его - найти код расшифровки, выяснить что ему нужно, составить своё приложение с этим кодом либо модифицировать оригинальное так чтобы этот код отработал.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо за ответ! Я думаю, что это пока слишком сложно для меня.